# How to set the default language of date in R

Tags: r

I used a R package written by other people. In the package, it is supposed to create a file name as "Mar.12". However the file name is "三月.12” in my system since I am running it on an OS with Chinese language (windows 10). I have changed the display language to English in the Rconsole file but it does not help. I am wondering is there any method to change the default date to English in R without revising the original package?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your description, it appears to be the issue of your locales. Read `?locales` for more.

You can have a test with this (read `?strptime` for various format, and pay special attention to those sensitive to locales):

```
format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%b-%d")
# [1] "2016- 9月-06"
```

The output has the month in Chinese. If I want to change the display, I need to set `"LC_TIME"` locale to `"C"`:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

Then it is OK:

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%b-%d")
# [1] "2016-Sep-06"
```

Every time you start a new R session, you get back to native setting. Should you want a permanent change, put

```
.First <- function() {
   Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
   }
```

in the `$(R RHOME)/etc/Rprofile.site` file. Read `?Startup` for how to customize R startup and the use of `.First`.

Comment: You can also use the .Rprofile project file to run the Sys.setlocale() function, so every time the project is loaded, the setting will be configured but only for that project, so it doesn't affect to the rest of your R environment.

Answer (score 29):

More info :
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html

You'll get all your local variables through:  `sessionInfo()`

### Exemple From R doc :

```
Sys.getlocale()
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
```

### Set your language

#### Windows

- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "German")`
- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`
- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "French")`

#### Other

- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de")`     # Solaris: details are OS-dependent
- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")`  # Many Unix-alikes
- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")`  # Linux, macOS, other Unix-alikes
- `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.utf8")`   # some Linux versions

Comment: On Linux, you will likely also need to do `sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8; sudo update-locale` to make a locale available at the OS level.

Comment: add the Sys.setlocale() statement to your .Rprofile project file, so it will be automatically set every time the project is loaded without affecting your whole R environment.

Comment: @AlpiMurányi that would affect your whole OS configuration, and it is probably not what you might want.