# Issue: how can I express a date written in text as numerical?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am scraping hotel reviews from the following TripAdvisor page:

```
library(rvest)
web <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187507-d228530-Reviews-Melia_Maria_Pita-La_Coruna_Province_of_A_Coruna_Galicia.html")
```

I want to get the rating dates in order to express the number of Reviews per week, but I am not able to express the date in the appropiate format. I tried the following, but it gives me

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

```
dateComment<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%
  html_attr("title")
```

I have also tried with html_text which gives me the date in written format. However, when I tried to express it as date format it gives me error:  do not know how to convert 'df$fechaComentarios' to class “Date”

```
dateComment<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%html_text() 

df$dateComment=gsub("de","",df$dateComment)
df$date <- as.Date(df$fechaComentarios, format = "%d %B %Y")
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because you did not properly extract the date.

```r
library(rvest)

web <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187507-d228530-Reviews-Melia_Maria_Pita-La_Coruna_Province_of_A_Coruna_Galicia.html")

dateComment<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%html_text()

head(dateComment)
```

Leads to

```r
c("Fecha de la estancia: marzo de 2020", "Fecha de la estancia: octubre de 2019", 
"Fecha de la estancia: febrero de 2020", "Fecha de la estancia: febrero de 2020", 
"Fecha de la estancia: febrero de 2020")
```

The following extracts the date correctly.

```r
dateComment <- strsplit(dateComment, ": ")

dateComment <- unlist(lapply(dateComment, FUN = function(x) {x[2]}))

head(dateComment)
> [1] "marzo de 2020"   "octubre de 2019" "febrero de 2020" "febrero de 2020" "febrero de 2020"
```

For `as.Date` to work correctly, you have to use the correct time setting. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340185/how-to-set-the-default-language-of-date-in-r) for details.

Comment: Great! Can you please mark my answer then as correct and give it an UpVote? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @MacOS points out, you need to extract the text. That text string also comes along with `Fecha de la estancia:`, but you can easily get rid of that using `str_extract`.

The main issue is that you're trying to parse a date without a day into class `POSIXct`, which can't work.

One approach would be to `paste` on an arbitrary day, say `01` and then use `lubridate::parse_date_time` to parse.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
web%>%
  html_nodes(
    ".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa") %>%
  html_text %>%
  str_extract("(?<=: ).+") %>%
  paste0("01 ",.) %>%
  parse_date_time("%d %B %Y",locale = "es_ES")
#[1] "2020-03-01 UTC" "2019-10-01 UTC" "2020-02-01 UTC" "2020-02-01 UTC" "2020-02-01 UTC"
```

You can probably skip the `locale = "es_ES"` argument, but I'm in the US and using English, so I had to use that.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful

Comment: @IanCampbell It seems we have a draw here. :D