# How to convert to character to date in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to convert this column to date as %m-%d-%Y-HMS, and remove the milliseconds. How to do this?

```
df <- tribble(
 ~date,   
   "Februar 1st 2021, 06:34:53.190",
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have locale same as the data that you have using `lubridate`'s `mdy_hms` should work.

```
df$date <- lubridate::mdy_hms(df$date)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. It gives me the following error: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: I think 190 (a millisecond) should be removed first or?

Comment: Nope. This is locale dependent. `lubridate::mdy_hms("February 1st 2021, 06:34:53.190")` works for me. "Februar" I guess is in German? You need to change your locale accordingly. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154187 which might help you do that.