# Spanish dates in R

Tags: r, csv, date, vector

I have a vector of dates in R I must modify. The dates, however, are in Spanish. How do I work the data if it's not in English?

As an example, "Jan 02 1987" is "ene 02 1987"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (temporarily) change your language to "Spanish" with `Sys.setlocale()`. For example, on my Windows machine, the following works

```r
# My default locale is (Australian) English
x <- c("Jan 02 1987", "ene 02 1987")
as.Date(x, "%b %d %Y")
#[1] "1987-01-02" NA 

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")
as.Date(x, "%b %d %Y")
#[1] NA           "1987-01-02"
```

Based on your OS, you might have to use a slightly different `Sys.setlocale()` call.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340185/how-to-set-the-default-language-of-date-in-r) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If `Sys.setlocale` doesn't work, you can use `parse_date`function from `readr` package.

For example,

```
parse_date(c("ene. 30 2016", "feb. 1 2017"), "%b %d %Y", locale = locale("es"))
```

will return

```
[1] "2016-01-30" "2017-02-01"
```

(month is printed in number because of my Sys.locale. It will not matter.)

If your vector does not have `.` after month,

```
x <- c("ene 30 2016", "feb 1 2017")    
parse_date(paste(paste0(word(x,1), "."), word(x,2,3)), "%b %d %Y", locale = locale("es"))
```

will work.