# R Lubridate dmy output format

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm working with Lubridate package for formatting the dates in my data.

```
    str(base$date)
    #>  chr [1:38] " 23.09.2020 " " 23.09.2020 " " 17.06.2020 " " 03.06.2020 " ...
    base$date <-dmy(base$date)
    str(base$date)
    #>  Date[1:38], format: "2020-09-23" "2020-09-23" "2020-06-17" "2020-06-03" "2020-05-27" ...
```

Since my original data for the dates are in format character, I wanted to convert it in to format date (dd/mm/yyyy) with function dmy of Lubridate package. And I'm getting format date in yyyy/mm/dd. Is't the function dmy supposed to give me the date in dd/mm/yyyy since d stands for day, m stands for month and y for year ?

Comment: As David said, a date object is YYYY-MM-DD format. dmy function is written as "dmy" to make clear the input provided should be in dd/mm/yyyy format, but not the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lubridate::dmy()` creates a date-object **from** a string in the DMY format.

When you print a date object, it is by default shown in the ISO 8601 format aka YYYY-MM-DD.

To print the date in the DMY format, you can use `format(date, "%d/%m/%y")` (note that this will convert the date object to a string).

To change the default way dates are printed, you have to look at locales (eg see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340185/how-to-set-the-default-language-of-date-in-r)).